# Calculating in Ext Xtemplate

Tags: javascript, extjs

I try to do a calculation in a Ext XTemplate. According to the docs i read that is possible with a simple {x + y} tag, but that din't work with 2 variables, so i tried doing it with {[x + y]} but then the template rendering stops after that.

```
var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate('{x} + {y} = {[x + y]} thats it.');
console.log( tpl.apply({x: 1.5, y: 2}) );​
```

results in.

```
1.5 + 2 =
```

I've made jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VnFR3/1/ with how I tried.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate('{x} + {y} = {[values.x+values.y]} thats it');
console.log( tpl.apply({x: 1.5, y: 2}) );
```

Alternative with functions:

```
var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate('{x} + {y} = {[values.x+values.y]}  or ',
                            '{[this.add( values.x,values.y )]}',{
    add:function(x,y){
        return x+y;
    }
});
console.log( tpl.apply({x: 1.5, y: 2}) );
```

The important distinction from your code is the use of **values** object inside the [] code execution template. The docs do not make that clear enough.